# Is my computer compatible with Ubuntu 12.10 64-bits?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if my CPU is AMD64 compatible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133111/how-can-i-check-if-my-cpu-is-amd64-compatible)

I am currently under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit because when I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 it was horrifically slow and crashed after 10 minutes of use by freezing.

I would like to know, from a ubuntu command or menu, if my computer is compatible with Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit. Also, do you think that upgrading will resolve my problem or does it come from something else?

Thanks, mjchopperboy

Comment: Is your system 32 or 64-bits?

Comment: That's what I would like to know. I am using 32-bit but am I compatible with 64-bit? Is there some kind of command to know that?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133111/how-can-i-check-if-my-cpu-is-amd64-compatible

Comment: Please tell us more information about your computer, including the tech specs and recently installed softwares.

Comment: @Rinzwind The above link you have posted is largely unrelated to the question. The link tells you about AMD. In this question, he did not state he is using AMD.

Comment: @tech It refers to the architecture which is AMD64 or i386. It is named such because AMD was the 1st to introduce 64 bits. The "CPU  op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit" refer to your system being able to support a 64 bit OS and has nothing to do with amd motherboards or intel motherboards being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are uncertain, there is no harm in trying the 64-bit version. If your machine turns out to be 32-bit only, the installer will simply fail right at the beginning while letting you know that you have the wrong version of the kernel.

1. Try installing 64-bit version.
2. If it fails, install 32-bit version. No harm done.

Comment: Sorry but no. There is a command for this `lscpu` as shown in the URL in comment.

Comment: If you could please put that as an answer, I would validate it. I read your link but could not add as best answer, as it is a comment.

Comment: @farid please upvote the answer in the URL I posted (I so not need reputation for someone else his/hers answer ;) )

Comment: Of course, you can usually find out somehow if your CPU is 64-bit compatible or not. My point is simply that, if you are the least bit uncertain, there is absolutely no harm in trying the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

64 bit is about memory addressing. So if your computer has more than 4 gig memory you use 64bit if less you use 32 bit. There is no command that will tell you if you are compatible.

Best thing to do is use the "Live CD" and test it out. That way you can see if its compatible with your wifi and screen which are the most important aspect.

Comment: Sorry but no. There is a command for this lscpu as shown in the URL in comment. He is already using Ubuntu. Why make life difficult if the answer is 1 terminal command away?

Comment: CPU is a small part of compatabily, I think checking that all the other bits like video cards, ethernet and wifi is more important to know.