# Is it possible to install 64 bit ubuntu desktop/server to a Compaq Mini 110?

Tags: 14.04, server, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a Compaq Mini 110. I can install 32bit version of Ubuntu desktop and it works fine. But when I try to install Ubuntu server 32Bit/64Bit or Desktop 64Bit, the screen freeze after choosing "Install ubuntu".

Is this because my device does not support 64Bit or 32 Bit server or something else?

Comment: You might want to [check if your cpu is 64bits compatible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133111/how-can-i-check-if-my-cpu-is-amd64-compatible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a 32 bit laptop, 64 bit is not possible to be installed in this machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse your laptop has an processor that does not support 64bit, and is 32-bit only. You've gonna update the well, entire laptop to 64bit which can cost lots of money!